# Get the list item postion of the list view from mobile switch

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I'm fairly new to kendo mobile. I created a custom list view from a template each item will have mobile swith on it. I want to get the position of the list item once the user clicks mobile swtich via onChange event of the mbile switch. Is this possible ? Please help  ;-)

Cheers

Chinthaka

Comment: show us your attempt and explain where it fails

Comment: Hi Lars thanks for your response here is how I'm goind to bind the mobile switch Template Code : <a> #: name #</a> <input id="mobile-switch" data-role="switch"  data-change="app.watchguard.switchChange"  checked="checked" data-enable="false"/>

Comment: Great I got the pos id with this code :                                    var pos =  e.sender.element.closest('[li]').context.id;